# Can a Java Bean validation annotation (javax.validation) use Spring config properties for the annotation properties?

Tags: spring, bean-validation

I often use javax.validation constraints for validating input in Spring (Boot) apps. For example:

```java
public class AccountDTO {
    @Size(max = 25)
    private String name;
}
```

Problem is, that "magic number" literal of 25 violates DRY - it has to match what's in other places, such as the UI.

I'm looking for an easy way to define the value as a custom config property, like this:

```yaml
myApp:
  accounts:
    maxNameLength: 25
```

And then reference that in the annotation.

One of the challenges is that many of the javax.validation annotations have params that are `int`, so SpEL can't help. I've seen examples of custom validation annotations and validators that use a `PropertyResolver` to look up values, but it's a lot of hoops to jump through just to do something it seems Spring could provide. Just wondering if there's a simpler solution than writing a custom validation constraint.

Comment: Can't we use string constants? It will atleast be reusable throughout the backend. What are the advantages of having config property over string contant?

Comment: Yes, that's an option; it's how I've worked around it several times. But for some of these values, there's a desire for them to be driven by configuration.